# select tag not honoring name field - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

Do you have any idea why the name (="language") here is not being honored? I expect it to be in the search query.. but instead it spits out something ugly like "company%5Blanguage%=".

```
<%=select( :company,:language,{'Italian' => 'Italian', 'English' => 'English','Italian and English' => 'Italian and English'},{:name => "language", :prompt=>true} )
```

I have tried to take it out of the brackets by the way.. no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ah interesting. In case this will help someone, here is my solution

```
select( :company,:language,{'Italian' => 'Italian',..},
{:name => "language", :prompt=>true},{:name => 
"language"}
```

The reason is that the form of the select tag is

```
select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

and you need to make sure the :name is set in html_options.

Thanks!